# Netlogo foreach nested list

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to port an older code to the latest (6.0.1), the following foreach loop works fine on Netlogo 4.1.3 but when copy and paste the code into version 6.0.1 the "item 0 ?" does not work. It says the "?" is undefined. That line of code is suppose to retrieve the item of the list inside the segment

```
to setup-row [row colour segments]
  foreach segments
  [
      if pycor = row * row-patches-width and
        (pxcor >= col-patches-width * (item 0 ?)) and (pxcor <= col-patches-
         width * (item 1 ?))
          [set pcolor colour
            output-print item 0 ?]
  ]
end
```

The passed in "segments" variable contains the following lists:

```
  setup-row  4 blue [[-8 -5] [-3 -1] [0 3] [5 9]]
```

If the code is working correctly, it should retrieve the -8 with (item 0 ?) and -5 with (item 1 ?) and so on. What I assumed in the old code is that the "?" are the first list retrieved from segments which is [-8 -5] and (item 0 ?) retrieved the -8 and (item 1 ?) retrieved the -5.

I have tried to read through the new user manual to find something that works similarly but to no avail or maybe I didn't look in the right place. Hope some of you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, that's been changed in Netlogo 6.0- see the [transition guide page](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#v60). For more detail on the new `foreach` syntax, see the [dictionary entry](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#foreach). Basically, instead of using `?` now, you explicitly define the variable names to use in the `foreach` procedure. Following your list example above:

```
to foreach-example

  let ex [ [-8 -5] [-3 -1] [0 3] [5 9] ]

  foreach ex [
    [ xy_coords ] ->
    ask patches with [ pxcor = (item 0 xy_coords) and pycor = ( item 1 xy_coords) ] [
      set pcolor white
    ]
  ]

end
```

Here, I explicitly state that the list items will be called "xy_coords" throughout the procedure. It's a nice change that allows for more readable code since your variables can have more meaningful names.

Comment: thank you for the example and the useful links. guess I wasn't looking hard enough, I was looking for something like the transition guide.

Comment: Yes, and in 6.0.1, you can (thankfully!) drop the brackets around the variable name when it's a single variable, e.g.: `foreach ex [ xy_coords -> ... ]`.